# How can I get the nodes of my model in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I created my network model as follows:

```
    httpController: HttpController {
        parameters:
            @display("is=s;p=98.8575,423.675;i=block/cogwheel");
    }

    host[numclients]: StandardHost;
    server1: StandardHost {
        @display("i=device/server;p=1400.145,223.94249");
    }

    server2: StandardHost {
        parameters:
            @display("i=device/server;p=1400.145,365.16748");
    }
    server3: StandardHost {
        parameters:
            @display("i=device/server;p=1400.145,488.235");
    }
    attacker1: StandardHost{
        parameters:
        @display("i=device/server;color=red");}
    attacker2: StandardHost{
         parameters:
        @display("i=device/server;color=red");}
    router0: Router {
        parameters:
            @display("i=abstract/router;p=1216.5525,365.16748");
    }
    router[numclients]: Router;
    visualizer: IntegratedCanvasVisualizer {
        @display("p=98.8575,254.205");
    }
    attacker1_router:Router;
    attacker2_router:Router;
```

I  also created a simple module with the following c++ function in their class:

```
void CoIDS::askForHelp(){
cTopology topo;
const char *typeNames[3];
typeNames[0] = "router";
typeNames[1] = "host";
typeNames[2] = nullptr;
topo.extractByNedTypeName(typeNames);
```

This code  is to get all the routers and hosts nodes in the model.
The problem is that I get error at  topo.extractByNedTypeName(typeNames);
saying that there is an error in typeNames and sometimes about the method itself. Can you help me in this? Anyone will help it will be  much appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extractByNedTypeName()` is defined as:

```
virtual void extractByNedTypeName (const std::vector<std::string>& nedTypeNames);
```

So it requires `std::vector`, not an array of chars.
Reference: [OMNeT++ Simulation Library](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cTopology.html#aaedf2f68eab98cb0b6fe6e656518f371)

Comment: Yes correct. 
You always direct to the point Jerzy D. I appreciate.